# CC mode: make Tab just insert one tab or complete, no auto-indenting

Tags: key-bindings, indentation, tabs

I am dissatisfied with current behaviour of Emacs in CC Mode. I'm not sure if this applies to other major modes, but that's one I'm currently struggling with. Here are my problems:

1. When I press tab, instead of inserting just one tab, Emacs either inserts enough space to match last line indentation level.
2. I also can't insert tab when on empty line.

I believe those are caused by `c-indent-line-or-region` function,   according to `C-h l`, but I don't know what I can do with it. Neither of possible values for `c-tab-always-indent` change this situation.

I found something about `tab-to-tab-stop`, and using it helped, however, it disabled expanding snippets from yasnippet or `<s` in org-mode.

My setup consists of Evil-mode, Company-mode, LSP-mode, and following directives in `init.el`:

```el
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)
(setq tab-width 8)
(defvaralias 'c-basic-offset 'tab-width)

(setq-default c-default-style "linux"
              c-basic-offset 8
              c-tab-always-indent nil
              indent-tabs-mode t)
```

`tab-to-tab-stop` has something related to expanding in it's source:

```el
  (and abbrev-mode (= (char-syntax (preceding-char)) ?w)
       (expand-abbrev))
```

but it doesn't help.

I thought I found solution in using `tab-to-tab-stop` with `c-tab-always-indent` to `'complete`, and it worked, for some time, but after I restarted emacs, it, again, has no effect.

```el
(setq-default c-tab-always-indent 'complete)
...
;; in configuration for evil mode
(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "TAB") 'tab-to-tab-stop)
```

So is there a way for me to make tabs stupid, i.e. **having pressing Tab just insert `\t` (or N spaces if configured so)**, while **keeping the ability to expand snippets** using it?

**EDIT:** 
After disabling tab-to-tab-stop and seeing with `C-h l` what exactly causes snippets to expand (`org-cycle` and `yas-expand`), I'm starting to suspect that there is some kind of function that tries to understand the context and apply specific action, and my evil-state map interferes with it, taking priority or something? Are my guesses wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```el
(setq-default c-tab-always-indent 'complete)

...

;; don't do this:
;; (define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "TAB") 'tab-to-tab-stop)

;; also don' this:
;; (global-set-key (kbd "TAB") 'tab-to-tab-stop)
;; (global-set-key [tab] 'tab-to-tab-stop)

;; do this
(define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "<tab>") 'tab-to-tab-stop)
(define-key c-mode-base-map [tab] 'tab-to-tab-stop)
```

Comment: this works? Not working with normal completion at point for me.

Comment: Yeah, does not work with lambdas either.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to insert a tab character, you can use `C-q <tab>`, and let the default binding for tab key as is.

With `C-q` you invoke `quoted-insert`, so the next key is not interpreted as a command, but inserted "verbatim" in the buffer.

`C-q` is also useful in other contexts. For example, to search for tabs character you can type `C-s C-q <tab>`.